# Unfortunately app has stopped working but runs after few seconds

Tags: android, permissions

I am developing an application for different medical tests. However when I start running the app on the emulator it shows "Unfortunately the app has stopped working-> OK" But after a few seconds it runs . Whenever I go to the main screen it shows the above message. However after I press ok the app runs as it is. There are no errors or warnings shown on eclipse. I have attached the manifest file. Can someone help me please??

**The manifest file is as follows:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mobility.ui"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.mobility.ui.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


        <activity android:name="com.mobility.ui.VTest"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            ></activity>

        <activity android:name="com.mobility.ui.ITest"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            ></activity>

        <activity android:name="com.mobility.ui.ATest"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            ></activity>

        <activity android:name="com.mobility.ui.Test"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            ></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Logcat:-**

```
08-14 00:17:12.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1345):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 00:17:12.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1345):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-14 00:17:12.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1345):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-14 00:17:12.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1345):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-14 00:17:12.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1345):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-14 00:17:12.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1345): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.igate.mobility.visiontest.ui.UIScreenActivity$1@b2ce2338
08-14 00:17:12.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1345):     at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:667)
08-14 00:17:12.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1345):     at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1453)
08-14 00:17:12.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1345):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:489)
08-14 00:17:12.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1345):     at com.igate.mobility.visiontest.ui.UIScreenActivity.onPause(UIScreenActivity.java:55)
08-14 00:17:12.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1345):     at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5335)
08-14 00:17:12.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1345):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1233)
08-14 00:17:12.120: E/AndroidRuntime(1345):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
```

The UISCreenActivity.java file:

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
          if (bundle != null) {

//            String string = bundle.getString(DownloadService.FILEPATH);
//          int resultCode = bundle.getInt(DownloadService.RESULT);
//          
//          if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
//            
//              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Download complete. Download URI: " + string,
//                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//            
////              textView.setText("Download done");
//          } else {
//            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Download failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
////              textView.setText("Download failed");
//          }
//          

          }
        }
      };


      @Override
      protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

//      registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadService.NOTIFICATION));

      }

      @Override
      protected void onPause() {
          if(receiver != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(receiver);
          }
        }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//      overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_in,R.anim.anim_out);
    }

    public abstract void setObjects();

    // setting click listener to a view
    public void setOnClickListener(int[] viewIds){
        for (int i = 0; i < viewIds.length; i++) {
            ((View)findViewById(viewIds[i])).setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    public void setInvisible(int viewId){
        ((View)findViewById(viewId)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

}
```

Comment: Amy, there must be the error in your logcat, please check it.

Comment: Post your logcat. There must be some error printing there. Also check on different devices.

Comment: what is the error, post red colored error from logcat

Comment: Error will be in java file, so please post related code.

Comment: Show your `onPause()` code.

Comment: @Aniruddha It shows an error as invalid character @ <action...

Comment: The onPause code:@Override
   protected void onPause() {
     super.onPause();
     unregisterReceiver(receiver);
   }

Comment: @Amy  your are trying to unregister a receiver which isn't registered yet log "Receiver not registered: com.igate.mobility.visiontest.ui.UIScreenActivity$1@b2ce2338"

Comment: @Amy post your UIScreenActivity.java .i think you are using registration.which is creating problem.

Comment: Check my answer. Are you getting `IllegalArgumentException`?

Comment: @UchihaSasuke I have posted the java file and 
Aniruddha I tried your answer but still did not work

Comment: I think you have registered and unregistered your receiver in your  master or parent activity.

Comment: @Amy where you exactly registers your receiver? I didnt found any register receiver code in this class.

Comment: @Giru Bhai it shows error.. Downloadservice cannot be resolved

Comment: @Amy  I used your "DownloadService.NOTIFICATION" from onResume method  in your question. I changed it see updated answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/25300752/991085

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Register your receiver in `onCreate()` method like

```
registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("com.mobility.ui.receiverAction"));
```

And unregisterReceiver  in `onDestroy()` instead of `onPause()` method as

```
@Override
      protected void onDestroy() {
          if(receiver != null) {
            unregisterReceiver(receiver);
          }
           super.onDestroy();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this in `onPause` method

```
protected void onPause() {
  if(receiver != null) {
    unregisterReceiver(receiver);
  }
}
```

Or you can use `try-catch` block.

The root of your problem is located here:

```
  unregisterReceiver(receiver);
```

If the receiver was already unregistered (probably in the code that you didn't include in this post) or was not registered, then call to unregisterReceiver throws IllegalArgumentException. In your case you need to just put special try/catch for this exception and ignore it (assuming you can't or don't want to control number of times you call unregisterReceiver on the same recevier).